# Would using a goto statement be faster than letting an if statement return false?

Tags: c#, performance

Im writing some very complicated real time anlytical algorithms in c# and speed is key for the success of my program. If I am unable to keep 45 processes of the changing data a second then the PID control loop on the other end of the TCP server will oscillate. I could re-tune the PID loop to run at a slower "fps" but that is improbable. Just thought Ill tell you that before you write answers that say "the difference is only 10ms so nothing really" cause those 10ms is a lot to me.

Would if be faster to use a `goto` statment like so.

```
if (GeneralDataDirection && UseMaxCandleData || GeneralDataDirection && !UseMaxCandleData)
            {
                Y1 = CandleStickWorkingData.Min();
                X1 = Array.IndexOf(CandleStickWorkingData, Y1);
                goto FirstPointCalculated;
            }

if (!GeneralDataDirection && UseMaxCandleData || !GeneralDataDirection && !UseMaxCandleData)
            {
                Y1 = CandleStickWorkingData.Max();
                X1 = Array.IndexOf(CandleStickWorkingData, Y1);
            }

FirstPointCalculated:
```

Or would it be faster to remove the `goto` statement from the first if clause and let the second if clause return false?

Comment: Why don't you test it?  When you care about performance you have to get some good profiling tools and use them.  There is no substitute.

Comment: @J I want a "perfect world" answer. So in theory what would the answer be.

Comment: I want a unicorn...  but I probably wouldn't use a `goto`, not in a high level language like C#.  My guess is that it's probably not faster but it's definitely very ugly.  Test it to be sure, but the compiler isn't stupid - if the branch is clear you can't outsmart it somehow.

Comment: If you like spaghetti code, and bad practices, and unmaintainable mess, by all means, use goto :) Also, read a bit about micro optimization and why it's evil.

Comment: There's no substitute for [racing your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). You can't create the absolutely best performing code in all circumstances by learning millions of "always write X rather than Y" rules. Most often, they don't even exist without tonnes of caveats that you'll never remember.

Comment: It's also worth noting that whatever code you are using to branch with, if you're worried about 45 calculations per second then you must be doing some rather heavy calculations - those are going to completely drown whatever time it takes to branch.  A few `&&`s and `||`s will take nanoseconds to deal with - it's going to be the calls to `.Max()`, `.Min()`, and `.IndexOf()` that you`ll need to be worrying about.

Comment: @J... would you suggest a faster way for calculating max's and min's. Its just a `double[]` array. Right now I am at ~47 calculations a second. I'm trying to get it to about ~52-53.

Comment: @Mozzie I think that's a topic for a new question.  Seriously, though, if you care about performance there is no substitute for profiling.  It will tell you exactly which lines of code are taking the longest to execute - this lets you optimize in a smart way rather than stabbing around blindly in the dark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need the `goto` at all, just use an `else if`:

```
if (GeneralDataDirection && UseMaxCandleData || GeneralDataDirection && !UseMaxCandleData)
{
     Y1 = CandleStickWorkingData.Min();
     X1 = Array.IndexOf(CandleStickWorkingData, Y1);
}
else if (!GeneralDataDirection && UseMaxCandleData || !GeneralDataDirection && !UseMaxCandleData)
{
     Y1 = CandleStickWorkingData.Max();
     X1 = Array.IndexOf(CandleStickWorkingData, Y1);
}
```

If the first condition is `true` the `else if` condition wont be evaluated and its essentially a `goto` already.

Comment: Beautiful simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "else if " solution is fine, but I feel that there are some misconceptions about how "if" affects performance. The real cost of "if" is not in the logical comparisons. It is in how it affects the CPU's branch prediction. A failed branch prediction disrupts the pipeline and would waste tens of cycles. Branch prediction is very dynamic and depends on how stable those logical values are. 
So in theory "goto" and also "else if" will be faster than an additional "if" statement. But by how much nobody knows. It depends on how those logical values change in runtime. Run some profiling if you really want to know. But when you do run your profiling, make sure those values change in the same pattern that they would in real use cases.

Answer (score 0):

In worst case scenario you would exchange one goto for three logic condition checks so yeah - that would be considerably slower for you.

Having said that, I have to mention that "else if" mentioned by InBetween is the proper way of solving this issue. Looks much more clean than goto offering identical performance.